# How to get the HTML element value by ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I wirte one HTML page with, the page can be displayed. But When I try to get the value of element in page, an error occurs. In JavaScript funtion, I want to use `Ext.fly("loginname").getValue()` or `document.getElementByName('loginname')` to get the input from User.

In Chrome, the `Ext.fly('loginname')` is `null`.

What is the wrong with me? Thanks everyone.

The code of HTML LOGINNAME page as below

```
items: [
    { 
        columnWidth: .33, 
        layout: 'form', 
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield', 
                fieldLabel: '<font color="red">*</font>User Login', 
                allowBlank: false, 
                width: 180, 
                name: 'loginname', 
                enableKeyEvents: true, 
                msgTarget: 'under', 
                listeners: {
                    blur: function() {
                        changeValue();
                    }
                } 
            }
        ]
```

Ext web page: 
[image]

Comment: You are not using selectors correctly. If you have the field inside a form, you can use `form.getValues().loginname` selecting first the form component.

Comment: Thanks. You are right.I find the error in getElementsByName(), should add the array"[0]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext js work completely different the way you think. In Ext js mostly we don't bother about the elements ,Its all about components and accessing the components have different ways. As of now seeing your code I can give you a solution which will work fine but it is not acceptable according to coding standards of Ext js.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=loginname]')[0].getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems like document.getElementsByName()[0].

Comment: Yeah but this will pull components, But remember we have so many to access the component andvalues .